# Retry Geolocation request without refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have a specific issue with the Geolocation api. This is my scenario:

1. User landed on a page ( in Chrome - Android ) with GPS location disabled.
2. There is a button on the page, and onClick of the button triggers the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition`
3. Geolocation goes to the error callback with error message “User denied Geolocation”
4. User goes to Android settings ( mostly in notification drawer ) and turn on the location
5. User click the button again ( at this time,  location is available ) to get the coordinates
6. However, Geolocation api still throws the error “User denied Geolocation”

—

7. At this time, the geolocation request will work only if the user refreshes the page and press the button ( note: the location is still enabled )

Is there a way to make this work without the browser refresh ?

Here is the jsbin link: https://output.jsbin.com/pihenud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve this problem using an iFrame hack.

Here is the solution:

Instead of asking the permission in the main window, create an iFrame dynamically and call the `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` inside it. Now, we can use the `window.postMessage` to pass the position data to the parent browser window.

When we have to retry the geolocation request again, we just need to reload the iframe -- This will have the new site settings.

Here is the iframe code if anyone wants to try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Namshi Geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sendMessage = function(result){
      window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(result), window.location.origin);
    };

    var triggerGeolocationRequest = function(){
      var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 0
      };

      var result;

      if(window.navigator.geolocation){
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
          var result = {
            type: 'success',
            data: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude}
          };
          sendMessage(result);
        }, function(err){
          var result = {
            type: 'error',
            data: { message: err.message, code: err.code }
          };
          sendMessage(result);
        }, options)
      } else {
        result = {
          type: 'error',
          data: { message: 'No Geolocation API' }
        };
        sendMessage(result);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('load', triggerGeolocationRequest);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in your application code, you can have a utility to inject the iFrame. See the below code:

```
utils.getCurrentPosition = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.style.opacity = '0';
    ifr.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    ifr.src = location.origin + '/geo.html'; // the previous html code.

    document.body.appendChild(ifr);

    ifr.contentWindow.addEventListener('message', function(message){
      message = JSON.parse(message.data);
      if(message.type === 'success'){
        resolve(message.data);
      } else {
        reject(message.data);
      }
      document.body.removeChild(ifr);
    });
  });
};
```