# Retrying Geolocation after error in React Native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am using React Native's Geolocation API to get user's location or ask user to turn location on:

```
// Handle PermissionsAndroid
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    (position) => {
        // Update position
    },
    (error) => {
        switch (error.code)
        {
            Case 1: {
                // Ask user to turn on Location (Permission has already been asked for)
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Now, I want to retry the watchPosition if user ever turned location on at some later point.

Using AppState, I tried getting an event if user started to interact with the notification bar (maybe user is trying to turn on Location). But it only calls back if application is sent to background or is activated again (but not during notification bar interactions).

Since Geolocation conforms with W3 [standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/), I tried searching for solutions in web development world. But the only solution that I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381742/retry-geolocation-request-without-refreshing-the-browser), was using iFrame which is browser-only.

Also, a non-elegant solution would be to setInterval (say every 5 seconds) and then clearInterval only if a position has been returned.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate the flow by getting the current location first, then create the watch. The following is from the Geolocation docs.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      if (position) {
        //Handle first position
      }
    },
    (error) => (console.log(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
  );

  this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    if (position) {
      // Handle new position
    }
  });
```

I've found this recovers from location errors itself, as well as handling permission requests (tested on iOS 10).